# Run on server option does not display in eclipse helios for spring-maven project

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, maven, eclipse-plugin

I have imported maven project in eclipse and configured properly. Its a web application, however I can't see 'Run on Server' option on right click in 'Run As'. I have Eclipse Helios and maven, tomcat plugin installed. should it required any plug-in for this or we need to convert project. Other web applications are getting 'Run on Server' option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

check Project properties / Project Facets / Dynamic Web module.

Comment: @abalogh: should i need to convert project so that it will show run on server option? I dont have any idea about project facets. could you please provide more details about this.

Comment: Right click on the project -> Properties. There, look for 'Project Facets' in the left pane. Click on it. On the right pane you should see a list of facets. Check the Dynamic Web module one. (As in click on the checkbox)

Comment: @ablogh: I have convert to 2.4 version. but in my project folder it adds web content folder. but i dont want to modify my existing structure. also it display classnotfound exception for listner. when I import same project in spring source tools it does not required any conversion but it slow down my pc.

Comment: which version of STS are you using? versions before 2.6.0 SR were kinda buggy and slow, try to download the latest stable version.

Comment: @abalogh: I m using sts 2.5 version. Is there any  way to update this version to latest version..

Comment: Well yes, download the new version (i suggest not to use the installer, just download the zip and unzip it wherever) and delete the current one: http://www.springsource.com/downloads/sts

Comment: Hi all : i was able to find out plugin required run on server option for spring maven project. you need add this link[http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e-extras] and select maven integration for WTP and install it

Answer (score 0):

You might find this helpful;
http://vijaypm.blogspot.com/2010/12/maven-eclipse-and-tomcat.html

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, unable to run on a server due to project facet validation issue.

I'm using Eclipse "Juno Service Release 2".
And resolved the issue with the following steps:

1. Right click on the project (on Project Explorer)
2. Click on Properties
3. Click on Project Facets
4. Uncheck the unwanted Project Facet(s).
   Eg., I have unchecked Oracle WebLogic Web App Extensions
       (because, my server is Apache Tomcat 7)
5. Apply >> OK
6. Now, I am able to run my web app on Tomcat server.

Hope this will work your you too.

Thanks,
Maris

Answer (score 0):

"Run on Server" option is not displayed in eclipse- Spring MVC project
1)Click on properties->Project Facets
2) Select Dynamic Web module

Comment: It will be helpful to explain in your answer what this actually does.  It sounds like you are implying if the user makes the change to their eclipse project configuration then they will se be able to see and use the "Run on server option".  However you don't really explain that to the poster.  Please explain in more detail the action to take and the expected result.